# How to save data between sessions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game and will have to save progress between sessions. Currently I am using this method for saving a PlayerState class:

```
// Get the user data path
string userDataPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "userState_" + username + ".json");

// Convert to JSON and save to file
string playerData = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
File.WriteAllText(userDataPath, playerData);
```

This is all fine when I am dealing with simple strings, int and stuff like username, level and coins. The problem is when I want to save other classes like equipment and heroes. For example I have an equipment class looking like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public enum EquipmentType { Armour, Weapon, Medalion, Horse, Cloak, Book, Horn};
public enum EquipmentGrade { Blue, Green, Yellow, Red, Purple, Golden };

[System.Serializable]
public class EquipmentData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    public string equipmentName;

    public EquipmentType equipmentType;
    public EquipmentGrade equipmentGrade;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float dropRate;
    [HideInInspector] public int ownedFragments;
    public int fragmentsToSynthesize;
    public int valorAttack;
    public int valorDefense;
    public int spiritAttack;
    public int spiritDefense;
    public int elementAttack;
    public int elementDefense;
    public int troopBase;
}
```

The player can enhance at least 7 of those and a total of probably 10 attributes for each equipment can be changed. The player will be able to have 100s of equipment in the inventory, all at different levels. I tried to add this inventory to my PlayerState which will hold GameObjects with e.g. EquipmentData attached to it but it seems like it doesn't work between sessions:

```
[HideInInspector] [SerializeField] public List<GameObject> inventory;
```

Unity will only save it during the session with an instanceID but it won't be useful if I restart Unity.

**Possible solution**

I could save into different json files, e.g. a username_equipment.json file but it will be enourmous and a pain to serielize/deserielize. And the solution will be hard to maintain if I update stuff for equipment, heroes etc.

**Question**

1. Can I somehow save GameObject or Classes in Unity to be able to use them between sessions?
2. If not, how can I save all this amount of data in a better way? (Subjective I know but I am running out of ideas)

Answer (score 1):

The same way as you've already done with your PlayerState.

- Move logic out from monobehaviours.
- Create a model with all the data.
- Serialize/deserialize this model whenever you want to do this.
- Pass your model as data source to your monobehaviour "view."

Comment: As I mentioned it doesn't work with e.g. List of GameObjects since it can't serielize that.

Comment: Do you want to serialize instances of the objects instead of their state? What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 0):

This is still pretty much he same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77088429/saving-listlistgameobject-with-jsonutility-tojson-not-working-in-unity).

The answer is pretty simple: Do not serialize `GameObject` (or any `UnityEngine.Object` reference type).

---

In your case here is what I would do (and basically is a bit extended version of what was already said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77096617/7111561))

Instead of using a

```
public class EquipmentData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    public string equipmentName;

    public EquipmentType equipmentType;
    public EquipmentGrade equipmentGrade;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float dropRate;
    [HideInInspector] public int ownedFragments;
    public int fragmentsToSynthesize;
    public int valorAttack;
    public int valorDefense;
    public int spiritAttack;
    public int spiritDefense;
    public int elementAttack;
    public int elementDefense;
    public int troopBase;
}
```

rather use a `ScriptableObject`. This way it is already an asset that does not live in the scene but in the assets and can be referenced anywhere.

The once you can collect from your scene (if that is required at all) will rather only reference such an asset

```
public class Equipment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EquipmentData data;
}
```

Then for the serialization it is extremely simple! All you need is  unique ID for your equipment instances.

=> Simply have a central manager/collection of them. Whether this is a `MonoBehaviour` or a `ScriptableObject` as well, depends on your use case again

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class EquipmentManager : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private List<EquipementData> datas;

    public EquipmentData GetData(int i)
    {
        return datas[i];
    }

    public int GetIndex(EquipmentData data)
    {
        return datas.IndexOf(data);
    }
}
```

So that finally when serializing you don't serialize the entire data but rather simply the according ids and when deserializing you get the according id and look up the corresponding data and instantiate and initialize a runtime object with that data.